# Discord.js v13 check if button already has been pressed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

is there a way using collectors/interactionCreate to detect if a user already pressed a specific button on a specific message? One way I tried doing it was to save it in an array like this

```js
const alreadyPressed = []
const filter = m => m.customId === "No" && m.messageId === interaction.messageId && m.user.id === interaction.user.id;
collector = embedMsg.createMessageComponentCollector({filter: filter, time: 10000});//86400000

collector.on('collect', async i => {
    client.logger("collector1 collected")
    client.logger(alreadyPressed.indexOf(i.user.id, i.messageId))
    if (alreadyPressed.indexOf(i.user.id, i.messageId)) {
        return i.reply({ content: `You've already voted ${i.user.username}!`, ephemeral: true })
    } else {
        i.reply({ content: `Thank you for your vote ${i.user.username}!`, ephemeral: true });
        alreadyPressed.push(i.user.id, i.messageId)
    }
});   
collector.on('end', collected => {
    client.logger(collected.size)
    // if (collected.size < 10) {
        
    // }
    delete alreadyPressed[0]
    delete alreadyPressed[1]
});
```

but the bot always ends up responding with "You've already voted" so what would be a viable way of checking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as MrMythical said, `Array#indexOf()` will just return -1 since it can't find it, I tried this out a little bit and found out that using and storing the values in an array is probably what your looking for. I put them together too since putting them seperate is not needed then I use `.find()` to search the array if it matches the users id and the id of the message that the button is on. This would be a viable way of doing it

```js
const alreadyPressed = []
const filter = m => m.customId === "No"
collector = embedMsg.createMessageComponentCollector({filter: filter, time: 10000});//86400000

collector.on('collect', async i => {
    if (!!alreadyPressed.find(id => {  
        return id.ID === i.user.id+i.message.id
      })) {
        i.reply({ content: `You've already voted ${i.user.username}!`, ephemeral: true })
      } else {
        i.reply({ content: `Thank you for your vote ${i.user.username}!`, ephemeral: true });
        alreadyPressed.push({ID: i.user.id+i.message.id})
    }
});   
collector.on('end', collected => {
    client.logger(collected.size)
    // if (collected.size < 10) {
        
    // }
    delete alreadyPressed
});
```

Comment: this one works but other's can't press the button now

Comment: if you want it to work for other's you need to edit the filter, edited the question so it works for others now :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Array#indexOf()` which returns `-1` if it doesn't find it (JavaScript sees it as a truthy value). I would also recommend you putting the values into an object or its own array (when pushing)

```js
const alreadyPressed = []
// ...
collector.on('collect', async i => {
    // logs
    if (alreadyPressed.includes({userID: i.user.id, messageID: i.messageId})) {
        return i.reply({ content: `You've already voted ${i.user.username}!`, ephemeral: true })
    } else {
        i.reply({ content: `Thank you for your vote ${i.user.username}!`, ephemeral: true });
        alreadyPressed.push({userID: i.user.id, messageID: i.messageId})
    }
})
```

Comment: just says "Thank you for your vote" all the time instead